# Select a valid choice..That choice is not one of the available choices

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Here is my models and form in Django postgres database.When I try to create the mapspot object I get a error "Select a valid choice" even though its just a relational object.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

class Map(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)


class MapSpot(models.Model):
    map = models.ForeignKey('polls.Map', related_name='polls')
    position = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(), size=2)
    position1 = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('map', 'position'))
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Map, MapSpot

class MapForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Map
        fields = ['name']

class MapSpotForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MapSpot
        fields = ['map','position']     


>>> form = MapForm({'name':'US'})
>>> form.is_valid()
True
>>> form.save()
<Map: Map object>
>>> for each in Map.objects.all():
...     print(each.id, each.name)
... 
1 Germantown
2 US
>>> spotform =MapSpotForm({'map':Map.objects.get(id=2),'position':'10,20'})
>>> spotform.is_valid()
False
>>> spotform.errors
{'map': ['Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.']}
```

Comment: If you pass a dictionary (usually a QueryDict), the form assumes it gets serialized a form of the form's data. In your case, it expects the ID of a model, not the model. Try `Map.objects.get(id=2).pk`, or even simpler `'map': 2`. It's quite clear when you think that the form's data usually comes over the network via a HTTP request where objects cannot go without serialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default form field for `ForeignKey` is `ModelChoiceField`. `ModelChoiceField` "validates that given id exists in the queryset". Try next:

```
spotform = MapSpotForm({'map': Map.objects.get(id=2).id, 'position': '10,20'})
```

- [`ModelForm` field types](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#field-types)
- [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield)